# python for blends / mixtures

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, mixture

I have 10 gasoline storage tanks with the following properties:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4DPv.png

I want to be able to create a 5000gal blend with specific property ranges for each of the P1-P13 properties.

ex:

P1:45-50%;  P2:50-150g; P3: <1g;    P4: <0.2%;  P5: <0.2%;  P6: <1.5%;  P7:2-4%;     P8:<0.3%;  P9:8-12%;   P10:2-4%;   P11:<0.8%;  P12:<50ppm; P13:30-33%;

I am trying to developed a PYTHON code that will help me see all the possible combinations of 50gal lots of different qualities to achieve the desired blend.

you can round the tanks volume to the nearest 10 to simplify things

Any guidance would be fantastic!

So far I have used a variable of the itertools combinations to create all possible blends and then filter them. However, this takes forever. The following is what I have been using for finding all the possible 50gal combinations to make the 5000gal blend.

```
from itertools import combinations
def unique_combinations(iterable, r=None):
    previous = tuple()
    for p in combinations(sorted(iterable), r):
        if p > previous:
            previous = p
            yield p
for p in unique_combinations(50gal_setlist, 100):
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can attribute a "score" to each characteristic using the weight of each one. Then display the recommended fluid with the function `round`

Comment: by "score" I mean the closest flui that matches the recommendations. E.g. : Quantity 23 means fluid 4

Comment: I have improved the question, maybe it is more clear what i need now! thanks for the help!